# flex: is there a drawing component inside flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Is there a vector graphics editing component inside flex, I mean component that allows to draw lines, curves, shapes and etc.

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** actually the question is "is it better to deal with flex or do something with my own hands, if I want to embed a graphic editor into my flash app"

Comment: What do you mean "draw"? If you want to draw graphics on a component, I suggest you see the [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) class

Comment: I mean something that allows to draw lines/shapes/... on itself

Comment: To allow the developer to draw? Or to allow the end-user of your app to draw at run-time?

Comment: @bigp,to allow user to draw at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw using the `Path` class.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html

It is rather uncomfortable to work with, though, using fxg graphics might be quicker and simpler.

Edit: Ok with the recent comments and edit of the question, this isn't right ofc. Wasn't clear at the beginning though.